# How to remove Load More button attached to State in React?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a "Load More" button that I would like to disappear when all of the information has been loaded on the screen. I know this is something that has been asked on Stack a few times, and I have tried to implement the solutions given in those questions. However, with my setup, the code does not work.

I'm not sure how to manipulate the state to make the button disappear when all the data is loaded, or if state is what needs to be changed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import labNewsJson from '../json/labNews.json';
import '../styles/News.css';
import Image from 'react-image-resizer';

var moment = require('moment');

const newsList = labNewsJson['news'];

const ImageComponent = ({ children, img }) => img ? (
    <Image src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/" + img} height={125} width={125}>
      {children}
    </Image>
  ) : <div>{children}</div>;

class News extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: '',
            limitTo: 5
        };
            this.onLoadMore = this.onLoadMore.bind(this) 
    }

onLoadMore () {
    this.setState({
        limitTo: this.state.limitTo + 5
    })
}

updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value }) 
}

render() {
            newsList.sort(function(a, b) {
                    var dateA = new Date(a.date), dateB = new Date(b.date);
                    console.log(dateB);
                    return dateB - dateA;

                });

            let filteredNews = newsList.filter((newsItem) => {
                return newsItem.description.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
                }
            );

            const news = filteredNews.slice(0, this.state.limitTo).map((newsItem, index) => {
                return <div className='newsContainer' key={index}>

                <div className='row'>
                    <div className="col-md-9">
                        <p><strong>
                        {moment(newsItem.date).format("MMMM YYYY")} 
                        </strong><br></br>
                        {newsItem.description}
                        </p>
                        <p>{newsItem.more}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className='col-md-1' id="hideDiv"></div>
                    <div classname='col-md-2' id="alterImage">
                        <ImageComponent img={newsItem.img}></ImageComponent></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            });


    return (
            <div className='container'>

                    <div className='pageTitle'><h1>Lab News</h1></div>
                    <div>
                        <p id="searchbox-container"> Search the News: 

                        <input id="searchbox" type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                 <div>{news}</div>
                 <button className='loadMore' onClick={this.onLoadMore}>Load More</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
 }
}

export default News;
```

Comment: How does your code knows that all the data has been loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button 
 style={{ display: this.state.limitTo >= data.length ? 'none' : 'block' }} 
 className='loadMore' 
 onClick={this.onLoadMore}> 
    Load More
</button>
```

Simply check if the data you are rendering has a length greater than or equal to the total limit. If it is set the buttons display to none.

Comment: I was trying to do that, but no values I use in place of the word "data" that you put in "data.length" work.

Comment: You need to provide more code i just put data there as an example. For your case I cannot tell exactly what you are rendering from.

Comment: Ok, I thought I might need to add the entire file. I've updated my original post to have the whole file included.

Comment: use newsList that is your data

Comment: Ok, thank you. I did before and I got errors, but something else must have been in the way, because now it is working. Although, it does not seem to work in Firefox or Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to guess what you want. But this is the usual pattern to hide something based on a given condition. This is how you'd hide the **button** when the **limitTo** is greater than the total of **News**.

That **total of news** is something you should get dynamically, inside the component or passed as a prop.

```
class News extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: "",
      limitTo: 5,
      isLoading: false,
      totalNews: 100 // you should get this dynamically from the list of your news.
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { totalNews, limitTo } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {/** Rest of your UI. */}
        {limitTo < totalNews && (
          <button className="loadMore" onClick={this.onLoadMore}>
            Load More
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  onLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      limitTo: prevState.limitTo + 5
    }));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a approach today and was successful in it. Basically, we will just check if the limit to is less than your total items and only if the condition is true "Load More" button will appear or else after complete loading of data it will just disappear. (just like a magic)

> ```
>    {this.state.limitTo < this.state.resultContent.length &&
> ```

```
      <button type="button"  onClick={this.loadMore}">
        Load More Result
      </button>
      }
```